# How to import and save all articles in my own MediaWiki database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, ubuntu-16.04, mediawiki

I have installed MediaWiki on my own Ubuntu server, with MySQL as database.

What I want to do is to import all English articles (only texts, not images) and save them in my own MediaWiki database.
How can I do this? If you have any experience with it, please let me know how to do it.

Comment: Do you mean importing the whole English Wikipedia? With or without history? It's going to take a long time, but see https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps/Tools_for_importing

Comment: Not just a long time, but a lot of storage.